# How are an $ω$-sequence of points and its limit defined?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Definition):

> If the space $X$ is sequential, we may say that $x ∈ X$ is a limit
>   point of a subset $S$ if and only if there is an $ω$-sequence of
>   points in $S - \{x\}$ whose limit is $x$; hence, $x$ is called a limit
>   point.

I was wondering how an $ω$-sequence of points is defined? Is $\omega$ a special ordinal?

How is the limit of an $ω$-sequence of points defined?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Yes, it is the first infinite ordinal. This means that the indices range over all ordinals $<\omega$, that is, the non-negative integers.

Comment: Thanks! Then how is its limit defined?

Comment: $\omega$ represents the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$. A $\omega$-sequence is just a fancy name for a usual sequence.

Comment: @azarel: Do you mean $\omega \equiv \mathbb{N}$? So a $\omega$-indexed sequence is a $\mathbb{N}$-indexed sequence, i.e. a sequence in the usual sense?

Comment: Tim, yes. $\omega$ sequence is a "regular" sequence. We make the distinction since often we want to allow longer sequences as well.

Comment: @Tim: The limit of an $\omega$-sequence is defined as usual. For every $\epsilon$ there is an $N$ such that $\dots$.

Comment: If you're interested in sequences indexed by bigger ordinals too, you can have a look at Wikipedia [Ordinal-indexed sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Ordinal-indexed_sequences) or [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100380/is-a-net-stronger-than-a-transfinite-sequence-for-characterizing-topology).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\omega$ is the first infinite ordinal. This means that the indices range over all ordinals $<\omega$, that is, the non-negative integers, which are often defined as the finite ordinals.

A similar definition would work for any ordinal $\lambda$. The indices then range over all ordinals $<\lambda$.

For example, if $n$ is a non-negative integer, viewed as an ordinal, then an $n$-sequence has indices ranging over the $n$ (informal) ordinals $<n$, that is, over the ordinals $0,1,\dots,n-1$.

But we could let $\lambda$ be an ordinal $>\omega$. It seems to me you are unlikely to bump into them soon. You can view $\omega$-sequence as an excessively  fancy name for an ordinary infinite sequence in the usual sense.