# Sequentially closed $\implies$ closed, but not Fréchet-Urysohn space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

My apologies for the confusion...

I guess I'm asking when a sequential space fails to be an Fréchet-Urysohn space.

Comment: Arturo: I don't see how that follows logically. " 
If sequential closure implies closure, then the sequential closure will at least contain the closure". Is there a proof for this?

Comment: Arturo: But I'm not sure why seqcl(A) should be closed or even sequentially closed...

Comment: I'm not assuming that the seq closure is closed, only that if a set is sequentially closed then it's closed , how do I know that seqcl(A) is sequentially closed?

Comment: Then don't use "sequential closure" in your statement, use "sequentially closed". In general, the sequential closure need not be sequentially closed, but I took your statement the way it was written, not the way you now say you meant it.

Comment: I've fixed the wording to accurately reflect what you wrote in comment, and deleted my comments as no longer applicable.

Comment: The example I've given in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/100521/) works too. (Although it was given there for different purpose.)

Answer (score 5):

A sequential space is Fréchet if and only if it does *not* contain a copy of the Arens space. This theorem is proved, and the Arens space is defined, in [Dan Ma’s Topology Blog](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/a-note-about-the-arens-space/). (Note the links at the end of the article to previous posts on sequential spaces that may also be of interest.) Note that the Arens space is not the [Arens-Fort space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space) described in Wikipedia; the latter is a non-sequential subspace of the former.

Answer (score 3):

The standard example for a sequential space that is not Frechet is Arens space. The space is described in a general topology book or in wikipedia.