# Example of sequential space which is not Fréchet

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

**Definition**:

> $X$ is a **sequential space** if, whenever $A\subset X$ and $A$ is not closed, there is a sequence $\{a_n:n∈ω\}⊂A$ such that $a_n→y$ for some $y\in A^c$.

Is there any example to show that a sequential space need not be a [Fréchet space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space)?

Comment: what you mean by  $Ac$?

Comment: @nanthini: It was in fact $A^c$, the complement.

Comment: Do you mean an example of a space which is sequential, but not Frechet? From the current version it seems that you want an example showing that no space can be both sequential and Frechet.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to link to the Wikipedia article about [Fréchet space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space) and not about [Fréchet-Urysohn space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet-Urysohn_space)? The latter class of spaces is often called Fréchet spaces, too; but the link you provided is about kind of topological vector spaces.

Comment: Very similar question (with somewhat confusing title - at this moment) is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132352/sequentially-closed-implies-closed-but-not-frechet-urysohn-space).

Comment: @seirios okay thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The standard example is the Arens space, which is fully discussed in [this post](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/a-note-about-the-arens-space/) to Dan Ma’s Topology Blog. In fact, **every** sequential space that is not Fréchet contains a copy of the Arens space.