# Is there a topology on the countable set which makes the space is not first countable but has countable pseudocharacter?

Tags: general-topology

I want to know is there a topology on the countable set which makes the space is not first countable but has countable pseudocharacter?

Thanks for any help:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pseudo-character is defined as
$$\psi(p, X) = \min\{ |\mathcal A| : \mathcal A \subseteq \tau_X\text{ is a pseudo-base at }p\text{ (i.e.} \bigcap \mathcal A = \{p\})\},$$
$$\psi(X)=\sup\{\psi(p,X) : p\in X\}+\omega$$
see e.g. [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~apollo/topodefs.ps).

---

The space $S_2^-$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100521/) is one possible example of a space which has countable pseudo-character and it is not first countable.

It is not sequential, hence it is not first countable.

Each point has a countable pseudo-base. This is obvious for isolated points. If we use the same notation as in the linked answer then $\{\omega\}=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty (\{\omega\}\cup \{n,n+1,\dots\}\times\omega)$. So we see that every point is a countable intersection of open sets.

---

This example is very similar to [Arens-Fort space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space), so you can try to have a look at this space, if you're more familiar with it.

---

Another standard example of a space which is not [first-countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable) is the quotient space $\mathbb R/\mathbb N$. Again, since $\mathbb N= \bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N} (\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \left(n-\frac1k,n+\frac1k\right)$, this space has countable pseudo-character.

EDIT: Sorry, I've forgotten that you want countable spaces only; $\mathbb R/\mathbb N$ is of course not countable. But $\mathbb Q/\mathbb N$ should work for the same reasons.

Comment: Mm, it's a good example!

Comment: I'm not familar with Arens-Fort space. Is this space also has countable pseudocharacter?

Comment: The proof for Arens-Fort space is almost the same as for $S_2^-$.