# How to explain "mathematically" why not every net is a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, nets

A past question ask to "Give an example of a net that is not a seqence and explain why mathematically".

I know that the function $f:((0,1),\leq)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a net (since $((0,1),\leq)$ is a directed set) but not a sequence because $((0,1),\leq)$ is not $\mathbb N$. But how do I explain this mathematicaly. Do I have to prove that $((0,1),\leq)$ is a directed set and $((0,1),\leq)$ is not $\mathbb N$? How to do that?

Comment: In a sequence every tail set omits at most finitely many points. Not so in your $f$. A clear distinguishing feature IMO. The question is vague anyway.

Answer (score 3):

No. You have to prove that $\bigl((0,1),\leqslant\bigr)$ and $(\Bbb N,\leqslant)$ are not order-isomorphic. In other words, that there is no bijection $\beta\colon(0,1)\longrightarrow\Bbb N$ such that $\beta(x)\leqslant\beta(y)\iff x\leqslant y$. That's easy, since there is no bijection *at all* from $(0,1)$ onto $\Bbb N$.

Comment: So do I just say that there is no bijection from $(0,1)$ onto $\Bbb N$ or do I have to prove it?

Comment: Do I have to prove it?  In a paper, you would site a textbook proof that $(0,1)$ is uncountable.  In a class where that uncountability has not been proved?  Ask the instructor.

Comment: More interesting examples are nets that are not even transfinite sequences, because then the result doesn't rely on a trivial cardinality observation (but +1 because a "trivial cardinality observation" is a simple answer to the OP's actual question). See [is a net stronger than a transfinite sequence for characterizing topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/100380/13130) and [convergence of nets vs. convergence of really long sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/232652/13130) and my comments to [Intuition behind nets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3341824/13130).