# Is this an example of a sequential non-Fréchet–Urysohn space?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be the set 
$X = \{ (0,0) \} \cup \{ (\frac{1}{n},0) : n \in \mathbb N \} \cup \{ (\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{k}) : i,k \in \mathbb N \}$. Points of the form $(\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{k})$ are isolated, a basis open neighborhood of points of the form $(\frac{1}{n},0)$ is 
$\{ ( \frac{1}{n} , 0 ) \} \cup \{ (\frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{k} ) : k \geq j \}$ and a basis neighborhood of $(0,0)$, is a union of vertical segments intersecting a segment $[0,a) \subset \mathbb R$. This is described in the picture below.

I think that this space is [sequential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) but not [Fréchet–Urysohn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Fr.C3.A9chet.E2.80.93Urysohn_space).

Take $A = \{ (\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{k}) : i,k \in \mathbb N\}$. Then $(0,0) \in \overline A$. There is no sequence in $A$ converging to $(0,0)$, but, $(0,0)$ is the limit point of subsequences of the set $\{ (\frac{1}{n},0) : n \in \mathbb N \}$ in which every poin is a limit of a sequence from $A$.

I have created this example a while ago, trying to build a relativly simple countable non-sequential space. I have asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465540/non-sequential-spaces) if it is non-sequential. But, looking again, I think that it was sequential but not Fréchet–Urysohn.

Am I right?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are the singletons $\{ ( \frac{1}{i} , \frac{1}{k} ) \}$ open?  (If so, it's easier to just say that these points are isolated.)

Comment: Also, would the basic open neighbourhoods of $( \frac{1}{n} , 0 )$ be of the form $\{ ( \frac{1}{n} , 0 ) \} \cup \{ (\frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{k} ) : k \geq j \}$ for some $j > 0$?  (_I.e._, open neighbourhoods of these points don't necessarily include points from any other vertical section.)

Comment: Yes, exactly. The answer to your two questions is yes. I will add it now to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is sequential but not Fréchet–Urysohn.

To give a perhaps more concise definition of the space, let $$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\langle {#1} \rangle}
X = \{ \angles{0,0} \} \cup \{ \angles{\tfrac{1}{i} , 0 } : i \geq 1 \} \cup \{ \angles{ \tfrac{1}{i} , \tfrac{1}{j} } : i,j \geq 1 \},$$ and topologise $X$ by the declaring the following families of basic open neighbourhoods:

1. each $\angles{ \frac{1}{i} , \frac{1}{j} }$ is isolated;
2. basic open neighbourhoods of $\angles{ \frac{1}{i} , 0 }$ are of the form $\{ \angles{ \frac{1}{i} , 0 } \} \cup \{ \angles{ \frac{1}{i} , \frac{1}{j} } : j \geq k \}$ some some $k \geq 1$;
3. basic open neighbourhoods of $\angles{0,0}$ are of the form $\{ \angles{0,0} \} \cup \bigcup_{i \geq \ell} U_i$ where $\ell \geq 1$ and $U_i$ is a basic open neighbourhood of $\angles{\frac{1}{i} ,0}$ for each $i \geq \ell$.

**Claim.** $X$ is not Fréchet–Urysohn.

*sketch.* Let $A = \{ \angles{ \frac{1}{i} , \frac{1}{j} } : i , j \geq 1 \}$.  Clearly $\angles{0,0} \in \overline{A}$.  Suppose that $\angles{ x_n = \angles{ i_n^{-1} , j_n^{-1} } }_{n=1}^\infty$ is any sequence in $A$.  If $\{ i \in \mathbb{N} : ( \exists n ) ( i_n = i ) \}$ is finite, then it is easy to construct an open neighbourhood of $\angles{0,0}$ not containing any element of the sequence.  Otherwise by passing to a subsequence we can assume that $i_n < i_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and from here construct a basic open neighbourhood of $\angles{0,0}$ disjoint from this subsequence.

**Claim.** $X$ is sequential.

*sketch.* Let $A \subseteq X$ contain all the limits of convergent sequences in $A$. We wish to show that $A$ is closed; *i.e.*, $\overline{A} \subseteq A$.  Suppose that $x \in \overline{A}$.  Note that if $x \neq \angles{0,0}$, then as there is a countable base at $x$ it is straightforward to show that there is a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$, and so $x \in A$. So let's assume that $\angles{0,0} \in \overline{A} \setminus A$.  We can show that the set $$\{ i \geq 1 : \text{every open nbhd of }\angles{\tfrac{1}{i},0}\text{ intersects }A \}$$ is infinite (since otherwise we could construct an open neighbourhood of $\angles{0,0}$ disjoint from $A$), and so we may enumerate it increasingly as $\angles{ i_n }_{n=1}^\infty$.  But then for each $n \geq 1$ we have that $\angles{ i_n^{-1} , 0 } \in \overline{A}$, and therefore by the above observation $\angles{ i_n^{-1} , 0 } \in A$. It is then easy to see that $\angles{ \angles{i_n^{-1} , 0} }_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $A$ converging to $\angles{0,0}$, and so $\angles{0,0} \in A$, contradicting our assumption that it is not!

Comment: ok got it. Thank you very much!!