# Sequentially open sets but not open

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Can anyone think of an example of a topological space that admits sequentially open sets that are not open?

A subset $U\subseteq X$ is called *[sequentially open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_open)* if the following is true: Whenever some sequence $x_n$ in $X$ is convergent to $x\in U$, then there is $n_0$ such that $x_n\in U$ for each $n\ge n_0$. (I.e., the sequence $x_n$ is *eventually* in $U$.)

An equivalent condition is that the complement is *sequentially closed*. That means that for any convergent sequence which lies entirely in the complement $X\setminus U$, the limit also belongs to $X\setminus U$.

Thanks!

Comment: This is basically asking of an example of a space which is not sequential. You can have a look on the Wikipedia article: [Sequential space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space). You can check some older posts on this site, such as: [is a net stronger than a transfinite sequence for characterizing topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/100380) or [Set that is closed under limits but not closed topologically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2838010). You can find several examples if you [search in $\pi$-base](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=~Sequential).

Comment: In fact, after reading more carefully, you might be satisfied with an example which is not a [Fréchet–Urysohn space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space#Examples). Again, you can [look into $\pi$-base](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=~Fr%C3%A9chet%20Urysohn). And you can also find some related posts on this site: [Example of sequential space which is not Fréchet](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/457020), [Sequentially closed $\implies$ closed, but not Fréchet-Urysohn space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132352) or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1425464.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be an uncountable set with the co-countable topology; a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X$ converges to a point $x\in X$ if and only if there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n=x$ for all $n\ge m$. Let $A$ be an uncountable subset of $X$ with uncountable complement; then $A$ is not open, but any sequence converging to a point of $A$ is eventually in $A$.

Of course that space is only $T_1$, but we can do better. Let $\alpha$ be any ordinal greater than $\omega_1$, and let $X$ be $\alpha$ with the order topology. $X$ is quite nice, being hereditarily normal. Let $A=\{\xi\in X:\omega_1\le\xi\}$; $A$ is not open in $X$, but $A$ is sequentially open, since every sequence frequently in $X\setminus A$ either converges to a point of $X\setminus A$ or fails to converge.

Comment: I didn't understand the second example, and in particular how show sequential openness. Per the definition of the OP, shouldn't  we show that for every sequence which lies entirely in X\A the limit belongs to X\A. Why is it okay that the sequence is only frequently in X\A and that it may not converge?

Comment: @roi_saumon: We’re not showing that $X\setminus A$ is sequentially open: we’re showing that $A$ is. To do that, we need to show that if a sequence converges to some point of $A$, then it is eventually in $A$. Equivalently, we can show that if a sequence is not eventually in $A$, then it does not converge to a point of $A$. If a sequence is not eventually in $A$, then it is frequently in $X\setminus A$, and in that case it either converges to a point of $X\setminus A$ or fails to converge at all, so it definitely doesn’t converge to a point of $A$.

Comment: Thank you I think I understand id now. Just to be sure : If $ (x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence frequently in $X\setminus A$ that would converge to an element $x\in A$, then every subsequence converges to $x$. But since $x_n$ is frequently in $X\setminus A$ then there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k\subset  X\setminus A$ that converges to $x$, which is not possible because the $x_{n_k}$ are countable and there limit $\cup_k x_{n_k}$ would be countable and but $x$ is uncountable.

Comment: @roi_saumon: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: thank you. In the first example, shouldn't it be the co-countable topology that has this property for converging sequences?

Comment: @roi_saumon: Ack! I can’t believe that it took almost two months for someone to catch that error. Many thanks; I've fixed it now.