# What separation properties are satisfied by the Arens space?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

The [Arens space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000156/) is obtained by taking a discrete sequence $\{x_n:n<\omega\}$ converging to $\infty$, then attaching another discrete sequence $\{x_{n,m}:m<\omega\}$ converging to each $x_n$.

This space is $T_1$ as points are closed. What's the strongest $T_n$ separation axiom we can apply?

Comment: It's clearly regular Hausdorff and Lindelöf, so strongly paracompact.

Comment: It's even ultraparacompact: every open cover has an open refinement partitioning the space. So we have (fully) T4 from paracompactness. What about T5 (collectionwise normality) or T6 (hereditary normality)?

Comment: Paracompactness implies collectionwinse normality. It's clearly hereditarily Lindelöf, so has these properties hereditarily.

Comment: @StevenClontz You probably meant T5= completely normal = hereditarily normal.  And T6 = perfectly normal.

Comment: Whoops, yes, thanks Patrick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is [zero-dimensional](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000050) as basic open sets are clopen. It's also immediate that the space is countable.

As noted in the preprint at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6086.pdf, all Lindelof zero-dimensional spaces are ultraparacompact, that is, every open cover has an open refinement partitioning the space. Given an open cover, refine it with countably-many clopen sets $\{C_n:n<\omega\}$, then refine it further into the partition $\{C_n\setminus\bigcup_{m<n}C_m:n<\omega\}$.

Ultraparacompact spaces are strongly paracompact (every open cover has a star-finite refinement) and thus paracompact (every open cover has a locally finite refinement).

The space is $T_0$ and regular, giving $T_3$. The space is then $T_2$ and paracompact, giving (fully) $T_4$.

As Patrick points out in the comments, we can also get $T_6$. Countable is hereditary, and thus the space is hereditarily Lindelof. Along with regularity [we have perfect normality](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000258).

Comment: The space is countable, hence hereditarily Lindelof.  And hereditarily Lindelof regular spaces are perfectly normal by [this](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000258).  So the space is $T_6$.  Feel free to add this to the answer to make it more self-contained.